# getting ftp return code 530 (not logged in) in welcome banner before paramiko tries to authenticate

Tags: python, paramiko

I am writing a python script using paramiko to automate a daily download from a remote ftp host. The script connects successfully but then says the banner is bad and quits. It disconnects before trying to authenticate.

I get this exception: "**SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner**", and according to the log the last line of the banner is "**530 Please login with USER and PASS.**"  Note the return code 530 which means "not logged in". I think this is what paramiko takes exception to.

I am indeed using a username and password (see code below) but the host seems to expect those before paramiko gets around to showing them. The problem occurs in `Transport.start_client()` which comes before `Transport.auth_password()` inside `Transport.connect()`.

When I connect manually from the command line I can trigger the 530 message with this:

```
ftp -nd ftp.server.com
```

(The `-n` prevents auto-login which I think is the cause of the 530, and the `-d` enables debugging so I can actually see it.) The 530 line follows immediately after the banner, but isn't actually part of it. I know this because if I remove the `-n` I don't get it, but am immediately prompted for credentials. So paramiko must be doing something analogous to the `-n` option.

How can I either...

1. prevent the 530 line in the first place, or
2. get paramiko to accept/ignore that line

...so it can proceed to authentication? I assume paramiko's more advanced features can handle situations like this, but I am at a loss.

### Details

Here is my code, which I think is pretty boiler plate:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import paramiko
import logging

logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko_log')

host = 'ftp.server.com'
port = 21
user = 'anonymous'
password = 'me@email.com'
# It is an anonymous server so I really am signing in with
# username 'anonymous' and my email address for a password.

t = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
t.connect(username=user, password=password)
ftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
# if I could get this far, this is where I would download the file.
ftp.close()
t.close()
```

Here is the log produced from running the above code:

```
DEB [20180725-08:52:34.230] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xb69bb090L
DEB [20180725-08:52:34.231] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.4.1
DEB [20180725-08:52:34.287] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Banner: 220-This system is for authorized users only.
...[several more 220 lines]...
DEB [20180725-08:52:34.289] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Banner: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.293] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1893, in run
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self._check_banner()
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2049, in _check_banner
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     'Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e)
ERR [20180725-08:52:36.294] thr=1   paramiko.transport: SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

I've tried...

1. increasing `Transport.banner_timeout` (a common suggestion for questions relating to this particular paramiko exception) but does not help because it is not timing out.
2. splitting `Transport.connect(...)` into `Transport.start_client()` and `Transport.auth_password(user, password)`, but it changes nothing. The problem is inside `start_client()`.

Comment: ftp, ftps or sftp?  Paramiko is for SSH access.  Standard ftp, which looks like what you're dealing with based on the ftp -nd command that you're showing us, isn't related to SSH and you wouldn't use paramiko with it.  If it's standard ftp, look into the python standard library called ftplib.  See https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/75602/understanding-key-differences-between-ftp-ftps-and-sftp

Comment: @clockwatcher So it's a classic case of using the wrong tool for the job. I mistakenly believed that ftp and sftp were related and that paramiko could do both.  Rookie move.  Thank you for setting me straight.